# What is the arrow operator in unsafe code?

Tags: c#, pointers, unsafe

The [DynamicNativeLibrary class](https://github.com/jhabjan/Ghostscript.NET/blob/master/Ghostscript.NET/Microsoft.WinAny.Helper/Interop/DynamicNativeLibrary.cs) inside of Ghostscript.NET makes use of unsafe code to load DLLs dynamically. The method `MemoryFreeLibrary` has the following code (line 629):

```
private void MemoryFreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule)
{
    if (hModule == IntPtr.Zero)
        return;

    MEMORY_MODULE* memory_module = (MEMORY_MODULE*)hModule;

    if (memory_module != null)
    {
        if (memory_module->initialized != 0)
```

What is the `->` operator and what does it do?

Comment: MSDN: [*Pointer dereferencing combined with member access.*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8bz4d5h.aspx)

Comment: @Ian Thanks I, obviously, didn't know it's name and googling arrow operator only turned up results to do with the lambda `=>`. Also my Google-Fu is lacking in searching for symbols.

Comment: That is indeed hard to search for. The symbols do end up searching apparently if you include other text; I was able to get it to show up as 3rd result when searching `c# -> operator`. Searching `c# ->` for some reason only pulls up a ton of results about `yield`. Searching `c# operator` it does not show up, so you really need `-> operator`.

Comment: @Quantic All I found was stuff about `yield` too, you are strong in Google-Fu!

Answer (score 1):

"->" means: Accesses a member of a struct through a pointer.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/y31yhkeb.aspx